# How to implement an array filled with objects inside a class in VBA

Tags: vba

I have tried to implement this several different ways and am obviously missing something.

Class CUnit which includes an array of CPanel objects -

```
Private pPanel() As CPanel

Public Property Get Panel(Optional RIndex As Integer) As CPanel
    If RIndex = 0 Then
        Panel = pPanel
    Else
        Panel = pPanel(RIndex)
    End If
End Property

Public Property Let Panel(Optional RIndex As Integer, Value As Variant)
    If RIndex = 0 Then
        pPanel = Value
    Else
        pPanel(RIndex) = Value
    End If
End Property
```

Body of module:

```
Function UnitBom(Unit As CUnit) As CUnit

Set UnitBom = Unit

Dim Panels() As CPanel
ReDim Panels(1 To UnitBom.NumPanels)
Dim PanelTemp As CPanel
Set PanelTemp = New CPanel
Dim i As Variant

For i = 1 To UnitBom.NumPanels
    Set Panels(i) = PanelTemp
Next i

UnitBom.Panel = Panels()
```

this works

```
Panels(1).Width = 1
```

When I run this I get "Object variable or with block variable not set."

```
UnitBom.Panel(1).Width = 2
```

You guys will have to forgive me because I have obviously not explained very well.  I need an array of CPanel objects inside a CUnit object.  The problem is that when I create the CUnit object, I dont know how big to make the CPanel array.  I was attempting to create a temporary array that is the proper size as soon as I know what that size should be and then set the CUnit array equal to the temporary array in order to "size" it.  There is probably a far better way of accomplishing the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what I can guess out of those (few) pieces of code of yours, there are some coding errors which I think derive from code logic to be reviewed:

---

**Get property**

code:

```
Public Property Get Panel(Optional RIndex As Integer) As CPanel
    If RIndex = 0 Then
        Panel = pPanel
    Else
        Panel = pPanel(RIndex)
    End If
End Property
```

should be rewritten because since you are returning a `Panel` type object (`...As CPanel`) you should add `Set` keyword before each `Panel` occurrence in the left side of assignment statements:

```
Public Property Get Panel(Optional RIndex As Integer) As CPanel
    If RIndex = 0 Then
        Set Panel = pPanel
    Else
        Set Panel = pPanel(RIndex)
    End If
End Property
```

but then again in case `RIndex = 0` you would get an error since you'd try to set a `Panel` type object to an array of `Panel` objects, which is quite not the same!

so you could adopt a `Variant` approach:

```
Public Property Get Panel(Optional RIndex As Integer) As Variant
    If RIndex = 0 Then
        Panel = pPanel
    Else
        Set Panel = pPanel(RIndex)
    End If
End Property
```

which would still (successfully) allow such a statement as:

```
UnitBom.Panel(1).Width = 2
```

but would also (unsuccessfully) allow such a statement as:

```
UnitBom.Panel().Width = 2
```

which you most probably (and hopefully, too) don't need, but nevertheless your class would actually allow it ...

so maybe you would review the functionality of your `CUnit` class and, for instance, adopt a default `Rindex`:

```
Public Property Get Panel(Optional RIndex As Integer) As CPanel
    If RIndex = 0 Then RIndex = 1
    Set Panel = pPanel(RIndex)
End Property
```

---

**Let property**

this would be used for such a statement as:

```
UnitBom.Panel(1) = UnitBom.Panel(2)
```

to have both `Panel(1)` and `Panel(2)` refer to the same `Panel` object

but then you have to use `Set` keyword once again

```
Public Property Let Panel(Optional RIndex As Integer, Value As Variant)
    If RIndex = 0 Then
        pPanel = Value
    Else
        Set pPanel(RIndex) = Value
    End If
End Property
```

Comment: @bluebass44, did you get through it?

Comment: @bluebass44,  it'd be nice of you to give proper feedback to people trying helping you

Answer (score 0):

Here line one is unnecessary.  I'm guessing that `Unit` has not been set and this is causing problems further down the code.

'Set UnitBom = New CUnit'
'Set UnitBom = Unit'

Here every reference in `Panels()` is being set to the same instance of `PanelTemp`.

```
For i = 1 To UnitBom.NumPanels
    Set Panels(i) = PanelTemp
Next i
```

This is what you actually want to do:

```
For i = 1 To UnitBom.NumPanels
    Set Panels(i) = New CPanel
Next i
```

Comment: When I do this  Set Panels(i) = CPanel, I get a run time error 424 - object required

Comment: Sorry about that. I left out the `New` keyword:`Set Panels(i) = New CPanel`.